# Renci SSH.NET: can create symlink, but deleting symlink fails, why?

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, sftp, ssh.net

I am currently trying to copy files using Renci SSH.NET to a Unix server using SFTP, and additionally, I want to create a symbolic link to the files I have copied. This is basically what my code looks like, note that the variable `sftp` is a working instance of `SftpClient`:

```
string symlinkSource = @"/msyerver/SymSource/Test001"; //source to link to, exists
string newPath = @"/msyerver/somedirectory/Test001"; //place where the symlink should be created
sftp.SymbolicLink(symlinkSource, newPath); //link newPath to symlinkSource, works!
sftp.Delete(newPath); //fails with exception!
```

The question is: how do I delete a symbolic link correctly? Please note: I only want to delete the link to folder `Test001`, not the referenced folder itself. Why does this not work? SSH.NET unfortunately does not throw a meaningful exception, the only text I get is "Failure", and since this internally works through some "Request" mechanism, I cannot debug the exact source of the problem.

When I look at the exception, I find:
`Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}`

So obviously, it looks like SSH.NET is trying to delete the linked folder. What I want is to delete the symlink itself, not the folder behind.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the way the `SftpClient.Delete` (and `SftpClient.DeleteFile`) are implemented, they cannot remove symbolic links. They first call `SftpSession.GetCanonicalPath` with the path, what resolves the link. So you are actually trying to remove the link target not the link itself, what fails for some reason.

There's no way to delete the link itself with the SSH.NET API.

Though with some reflection hacking you can bypass the `SftpSession.GetCanonicalPath` call:

```
public static class SftpClientExtensions
{
    public static void DeleteLink(this SftpClient client, string path)
    {
        Type sftpClientType = client.GetType();
        FieldInfo sftpSessionField = sftpClientType.GetField("_sftpSession", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        object sftpSession = sftpSessionField.GetValue(client);
        Type sftpSessionType = sftpSession.GetType();
        MethodInfo requestRemoveMethod = sftpSessionType.GetMethod("RequestRemove", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        requestRemoveMethod.Invoke(sftpSession, new object[] { path });
    }
}
```

With the above extension method, you can now use:

```
sftp.DeleteLink(newPath);
```

---

Better might be to grab a copy of the SSH.NET source code and add the method directly to the `SftpClient` class. And file a request to the [SSH.NET project](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) to support deleting links.

Comment: Since file deletion is involved here I would advice against hacks, and instead just delete link with regular ssh command (with the same library, just not sftp)

Comment: That's a hack too, as 1) you have no guarantee that the SFTP and shell use the same file system/path syntax. For example one can be chrooted, while the other not. 2) You have no guarantee that you have a shell access at all. 3) while the SFTP works the same on all systems, different systems use different shells/commands (the system may not even be a *nix system, what you seem to assume).

Answer (score 1):

This method deletes all the files in the folder including symbolic links

```
public void DeleteDirectory(string path)
    {
        using (var sftp = new SftpClient(ost, Settings.Instance.Deployment_user, Settings.Instance.Deployment_password))
        {
            sftp.Connect();
            foreach (SftpFile file in sftp.ListDirectory(path))
            {
                if ((file.Name != ".") && (file.Name != ".."))
                {
                    if (file.IsDirectory)
                    {
                        DeleteDirectory(file.FullName);
                    }
                    else
                    {                          
                        file.Delete();
                    }
                }
            }

            sftp.DeleteDirectory(path);
            sftp.Disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the reflection hack, grab the file item from list directory.

```
SftpFile[] listDirectory = this.sftpClient.ListDirectory(path.Substring(0, Math.Max(0, path.LastIndexOf('/')))).ToArray();
SftpFile sftpFile = listDirectory.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FullName.Equals(path));
sftpFile?.Delete();
```

Consider the fullname comparison